# Max int value in t-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, int, max

I want to verify the Max value of int with the column value is it possible?
eg:- `select * from table_name where column_name= Max(int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you want the row with the highest value, not the actual 2^31-1 value

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name DESC
```

If you have multiple values with the highest, to get all

```
SELECT TOP 1 * WITH TIES
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name DESC
```

Let us know if you want highest per a group or other column: [can be done too.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/how-to-get-the-max-row/1004#1004)

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table_name where column_name=0x7fffffff
```